# A star algorithm not working

Tags: java, algorithm, a-star

I implemented this algorithm based on the pseudo code on the Wikipedia page [link to page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) for A*, but it is not finding any paths. When I use it I never get to a point where the current node equals the goal. I think it might have something to do with my heuristic or the way that I am initializing the f and g scores, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

The size of the map I'm using is 1920 x 1080 and uses a cell size of 30.

```java
private ArrayList<Vector2> aStar(Vector2 start, Vector2 goal) {
    HashSet<Vector2> closedSet = new HashSet<Vector2>();
    ArrayList<Vector2> openSet = new ArrayList<Vector2>();
    openSet.add(start);
    HashMap<Vector2,Vector2> cameFrom = new HashMap<Vector2, Vector2>();
    HashMap<Vector2,Float> gScore = new HashMap<Vector2, Float>();
    HashMap<Vector2,Float> fScore = new HashMap<Vector2, Float>();
    ArrayList<Vector2> neighbors = new ArrayList<Vector2>();
    neighbors.add(new Vector2(0,30));
    neighbors.add(new Vector2(0,-30));
    neighbors.add(new Vector2(30,0));
    neighbors.add(new Vector2(-30,0));
    for(int i = 0; i < 1920; i +=30){
        for(int j = 0; j < 1080; j +=30){
            gScore.put(new Vector2(i,j),Float.MAX_VALUE);
            fScore.put(new Vector2(i,j),Float.MAX_VALUE);
        }
    }
    gScore.put(start,0f);
    fScore.put(start,heuristic(start,goal));

    while(!openSet.isEmpty()){
        int low = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < openSet.size(); i++){
            if(fScore.get(openSet.get(i))<fScore.get(openSet.get(low))){
                low = i;
            }
        }
        Vector2 current = openSet.get(low);
        if(current.equals(goal)){
            System.out.println("YES!");
            return null;
        }
        openSet.remove(current);
        closedSet.add(current);
        for(Vector2 neighbor:neighbors){
            Vector2 tst = new Vector2(neighbor.x + current.x,neighbor.y + current.y);
            if(tst.x > -30 && tst.x <1920 && tst.y > -30 && tst.y < 1080){
                neighbor.add(current);
                if(closedSet.contains(neighbor)){
                    continue;
                }
                if(!openSet.contains(neighbor)){
                    openSet.add(neighbor);
                }

                float tentative_gScore = gScore.get(current) + heuristic(current,neighbor);
                if(tentative_gScore >= gScore.get(neighbor)){
                    continue;
                }

                cameFrom.put(neighbor,current);
                gScore.put(neighbor,tentative_gScore);
                fScore.put(neighbor,gScore.get(neighbor)+heuristic(neighbor,goal));
            }
        }

    }

    return null;
}

private float heuristic(Vector2 begin, Vector2 end) {
    return  (Math.abs(begin.x - end.x) + Math.abs(begin.y - end.y)) ;
}
```

Comment: Did you get a failure? Of did you simply stop the algorithm because it took too long?

Comment: I got a failure.

Comment: the line neighbor.add(current); might also be the problem. You are editing the neighbours

Comment: That was it, I feel so stupid, hahah. Thank you so much. I thought that was only changing the local variable, but I forgot that Java's arrays don't work like that.

Comment: don't worry about it, took me quite some time too. However, depending on if diagonal movement is allowed, changing the heuristic will lead to an enormous speedup. You should also think about your implementation. For example, don't initialize all f- and g-scores to infinity, but simply treat them this way if they are not found in the hashmap. And use a priority queue for the openset.

Comment: The game I'm using this for doesn't use diagonal movement so the performance hit there is nessassary,  however the other tips should work just fine.

Comment: If performance ever becomes a problem. You can allow diagonal movement in the algorithm, and when a solution is found, project it onto horizontal and vertical movements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `neighbor.add(current);` changes the neighbour. Not only that, but you store that neighbour, meaning that this object reference will be kept and may be further distorted in future code.

Another problem is with your heuristic. You are using the Manhattan distance, meaning that there are a massive amount of paths that all have the same distance (so long as you never move away from the goal node, the distance will the same for each path). Try allowing diagonal neighbours, and using the euclidian distance instead of the manhattan distance.

Comment: It is most likely my heuristic, the algorithm works when it the goal is next to the start.

Comment: not likely anymore. If it was the heuristic it would simply take very long. Since you got a failure it is likely the neighbour problem

Comment: @JohnSmith since your problem is solved now, please consider accepting my answer so other people know this problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

It would be difficult to find the mistake in all that code. I will try, however I think that a better approach to resolve this problem will help you.

Consider making a class called, for example, `Node`, which for every Node n it has the following items:

- Path to the node
- Value of f(n), the cost of the path from start to n
- Value of g(n), the cost of the heuristic, this is from n to the goal.
- Element or label.

Then the pseudocode of a recursive solution:

```
search_a_star(frontier)
    if(frontier.isEmpty())
       return false
    //Select node with lower f(n) + g(n)
    node = selectNode(frontier)
    if node is goal then 
       return node //You have in the node the cost and the path
    else
       //Generate the neighbours of your current node. You should calculate the heuristing of each neighbour.
       neighbours = generateNeighbours(node)
       //Add neighbours to reducedFrontier
       reducedFrontier = frontier - node
       newFrontier = add(reducedFrontier, neighbours) 
       search_a_star(newFrontier)
```

You should keep a set of visisted nodes. Also when you generate the neighbours, you should make cycle control considering this cases:

1. If the generated node has not been visited, then you should add it to the neighbours set.
2. If the generated node has been visited, but the cost of the path is lower than before, then you should remove that node from visited set and add it to the neighbours set.
3. Else, do not add the node to neighbours set.